# Clothing stores never change products

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've noticed the first several boutiques in the game have stopped rotating their wares. This includes Laverre City, Santalune and Cyllage. However the other stores, such as Lumoise, still rotate their inventory every day.

At the beginning of the game I had the clock set ahead a few days (thanks to Animal Crossing) but I have since kicked the clock back, and the real time is now later than the latest the "wrong" time was set.

Why have the stores stopped changing? Does this mean there is nothing more to buy there or is this a bug or what?

Comment: I noticed that when I changed the clock back for DST (which we do twice a year), the Lottery place stopped letting me buy tickets. Previous generations made you wait 24 hours before daily events would work again if the system clock (or system itself) was changed, it may be the same thing at work here. Maybe try waiting 24hrs, if that doesn't work then it sounds like a bug :\

Comment: @Kai it's been several days actually. Lotto still gives me tickets though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quirk in how the shops work; the displays rotate every day, but they will not rotate to an item you have already purchased. This means that the day after you buy them out, their stock will remain the same forever.

Confusingly, stock will not always rotate to the next new item, however. Certain items show up on certain days. So if you don't stop in on the day that the new item appears, it may appear a store is completely sold out.

Best way to see if you're missing anything is simply to [check out this list by Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/customisation.shtml) and compare what you own. A store that has had no new products for days may suddenly have a new item if you check on the day an item you're missing comes in stock.

Answer (score 2):

The stores change clothing based on what day of the week it is. It seems that several of the cities have the same clothing no matter what day it is.

Here's a list from [Serebii](http://serebii.net/xy/customisation.shtml) showing you what clothes on which days is available based on city. Beware, however, since the list is probably not complete, and the female part is missing the dates/city entirely.

Comment: Ack, female clothes are what I'm looking at. The stores that stopped changing USED to change though, so I'm not sure what happened, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Hm looking over that list, I have a large portion of the clothes available. It's possible I've simply bought all items at those stores

Answer (score 0):

All the stores' stock's should change every day. You can search 'Trainer Customisation' in Serebii.net to see a list of all the clothing items and which day they have them on the shelves. An easier way to buy those items is to change your 3DS time. The in-game clock won't matter.

To get the Bamboo Sprig hat(Male)and Sundae Dress (Female) you must first bet the game and skate over to the TMV station and get your TMV pass, then ride the train to Kiloude town where you will find a Painter girl that wants you to wear a vividly colored hat and some (Male) or some very bright colors (Female). An example of a vividly colored Hat or Dress is a logo cap with matching sneakers.

If you're a girl I found that Frilly Pale Pink dress, a Pale pink Felt hat, Pale pink Ribbon purse, Pink Tights, a pink Artificial flower pin and Pale pink Mary Janes work well.

Comment: You should link directly to the relevant page at Serebii as a reference, rather than telling people to search it. It saves people a click